# Is it true that there are some principles of mechanical trasmissions and junctions that were known for long but became possible only recently?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics

Is this true that some parts of mechanisms, such as various types of transmissions or junctions, while were known theoretically for a long time, became possible practically only with advent of 3D printers because they need details of complicated curved forms and/or great precision, which were unable to be produced with other techniques?

Are there some examples?

P.S. Since there is misunderstanding, I mean basic principles or transmissions, not complete mechanisms like a mechanical computer or automatic rifle. I am also interested in *solid mechanics* examples, not thermodynamic machines, engines, turbines, pumps, etc.

Comment: your three questions can be answered with `yes`, `yes` and `yes` ... is that really what you wanted to ask?

Comment: The specifics in your questions are currently anachronistic because 3D printers are not known for their precision. You don't choose 3D printers for precision. You choose them for making inaccessible features inside something.

Comment: Is this for homework?

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial question.

Yes, a great many many ideas had to wait until technology caught up to be able to execute them. Everything mass production and parts interchangeability.

A classic example is firearms. All the moving parts tolerances in a modern firearm, and even before that, the lack of precision between bullets prevented rifling and breech loading mechanisms.

Another classic example is aspherical lenses. The necessary geometry has been known for THOUSANDS of years. Thousands! But we have only been able to mass produce them in the last 70 years.

For 3D printing, specifically, one class of mechanisms are called "flexible compliant" joints or mechanisms.

https://youtu.be/97t7Xj_iBv0?si=AUJds8ntNNGpXvHs&t=503
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FW6Vx2g9OCI
[image]

Comment: I was asking about mechanical principles, not chemical or optical.

Comment: I was asking about basic junctions like these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-42Z-_Kq0QU

Comment: @jsotola done. I underline that I am interested in examples exclusively from solid mechanics, not some novel form of turbine, pump or engine.

Comment: @Anixx Grinding an aspherical lens is a mechanical problem, not an optical one. It's a machining problem, like with lathes and mills.

Comment: I was looking for solid mechanics elements that were impractical before, not details of other devices that were difficult to make.

Comment: @Anixx I believe flexible compliant joints falls under this purview.